# Python + Requests как нажать на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, click

как нажать на кнопку с помощью requests?
Если не сложно можете быстро накидать пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особо никак. Зато легко через селениум.

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Пример:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Можно только посмотреть, куда отправляется запрос по кнопке (если вообще отправляется), и через requests уже отправить запрос.